# Ubuntu 18.04.2 - After upgrade facing issue with input type="password" fields - Loosing focus

Tags: 18.04, firefox

Ubuntu 18.04.2 - After upgrade facing issue with input type="password" fields - Loosing focus ...

I recently update and upgraded my system like every week. When I try to enter a value in a input type="password" fields on pretty much every website (using firefox), it constantly looses focus and it makes it almost impossible to enter a value.

How can I solve this issue? That's my setup:

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
...
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
...
~$ apt-cache show firefox | grep Version
Version: 68.0+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Version: 59.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Firefox Quantum 68.0 (64-bit) / Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical-1.0

I found a similar issue here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1765304

Comment: omg, i've been struggling whole day with it. in the end i did ```apt-get purge firefox``` and ```snap install firefox```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for now: Go to Settings/Region & Language/Manage Installed Languages and Change 'Keyboard input method system change' to XIM & restart ... seems to solve the issue. (previously unselected)

Credit to: https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2002#issuecomment-411218148